# PHP namespaced function collision

Tags: php, namespaces, name-collision

I use a namespace.

I have a function that has the same name as a native PHP function.

The issue is not that I create a function with the same name. It's when I try to use the native PHP function inside it. Then it uses MY function instead of the native one. That's because I'm inside the namespace.

Is there a way to call the `trim` function call inside the function without it using my namespace?

```php
<?php
namespace Hello;

function trim($some, $arg) {
  return trim($some, $arg); // Calls Hello\trim() which is not what I want
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\trim()` calls `trim` function from global namespace:

```
function trim($some, $arg) {
  return \trim($some, $arg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)

use `\trim()` to call the global function